# VB.net - "Dim x as new Y()" vs "Dim x as Y = new Y()"

Tags: vb.net

In our VB.net codebase I occasionally see `Dim x as new Y()`, where Y is a class.

What is this code doing and how does it differ to the more common `Dim x as Y = new Y()"`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They are exactly the same; the first is just a shortcut:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa903373

Comment: they didn't mention yet another variation of that: Dim x = New Y(), same end result, personally, I think it makes a tad more sense logically, but not by much<g>

Comment: @drventure - Dim x = new Y() does potentially have a different meaning.  You need to be more careful using type inference in VB.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Here's a quote from the [language reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77s47661.aspx) that shows that it is different. 'The following example requires that Option Infer be set to On.  `Dim intArray3() = New Integer() {6, 7, 8}`'

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [@Gendolkari's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464397/vb-net-dim-x-as-new-y-vs-dim-x-as-y-new-y/4464427#4464427), the code is exactly the same.  But I dispute that `Dim x As Y = new Y()` is more common.  I've seen a lot of code from a lot of different places, and `Dim x As New Y()` is a very commonly used shortcut.

However, it might be more common at your work place.  If that's the case, I have to come down against using the shortcut.  Coding standards are important.  If used correctly, even simple deviations like this are valuable because they set up easy to spot red flags that the code may need deeper inspection for other flaws.

Comment: I think also that the longer method is done by C/C++/C# people that are used to "Y x = new Y()" syntax that don't know about the shortcut.